# When is there an "intuitive" functor from F-coalgebras to T-coalgebras?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, coalgebras, natural-transformations

Suppose $F, T : Set \rightarrow Set$ are two functors on the category of sets.  Let $F^{coalg}$, $T^{coalg}$ denote the categories of $F$, respectively $T$ coalgebras.  Vaguely, I'm interested in when I can find a functor $G : F^{coalg} \rightarrow T^{coalg}$ that preserves my intuition from the final coalgebras of each functor.

Motivating example:

$F(-) = A \times -$

$T(-) = \mathcal{P}_{fin}(A \times -)$

Then $F$ has a final coalgebra of streams over $A$ (i.e. $F$ has fixed point of $A^{\mathbb{N}}$), and $T$ has a final coalgebra of equivalence classes of $A$-labeled transition systems with finite branching.

Now, my intuition says that I can map a stream over $A$ into a labeled transition system which has a path  (i.e. a subtransition system with no branching) that has the same sequence of labels as my stream.  But is there a way to formalize this mapping of streams into labeled transition systems via a functor $G$?  I see two potential problems trying to do so:

(1)  Streams and (equivalence classes of) labeled transition systems are the *final* coalgebras so although I described an intuitive map from streams to LTS's, I'm not sure what this map would like like for all the nonfinal coalgebras in $F^{coalg}$.

(2)  I want to suggest something like G being a natural transformation from the identity functor to $\mathcal{P}_{fin}$, but I'm not quite sure what to do with the object or structure maps and am also not quite sure how to think about the nonfinal coalgebras.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\eta : F \Rightarrow G$ be a natural transformation between functors $F, G : \mathbf C \to \mathbf C$. Then there is a functor $H : F\text{-}\mathbf{coalg} \to G\text{-}\mathbf{coalg}$. On objects, $H(A \xrightarrow{a} F(A)) = A \xrightarrow{a} F(A) \xrightarrow{\eta_A} G(A)$, and $H$ is the identity on morphisms, which gives $G$-colgebra homomorphisms by naturality of $\eta$.

For your example, note that $\mathcal P_f$ is a monad, and so there is a natural transformation $\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbf{Set}} \Rightarrow \mathcal P_f$. We can then [left-whisker](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/whiskering) with the functor $A \times (-) : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ to get a natural transformation from $A \times (-) \Rightarrow \mathcal P_f(A \times -)$, which induces a functor $(A \times -)\text{-}\mathbf{coalg} \to P_f(A \times -)\text{-}\mathbf{coalg}$.

Comment: That's great!  That answers a lot of what I wanted to know--I'm still trying to compare the final functor you describe against my intuition.  First, is this induced functor for the example cocontinuous so that the final $(A \times -)$-coalg is mapped to the final $\mathcal{P}_f(A \times -)$-coalg?   Second, is it really "a" functor which is induced (i.e. uniquely)?  If so, I am confused as intuitively, I can map many different streams / sequences into the same LTS so I would expect a whole family of such functors.  Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: Intuitively, the induced functor is extending the final $A \times (-)$-coalgebra map by taking each element of each a stream, and considering it a single-branching tree (as this is what the unit of the finite powerset monad is doing). This matches your intuition for how the functor should act. However, the underlying set of this final coalgebra (i.e. streams) is not the same as the underlying set of the final $\mathcal P_f(A \times -)$-coalgebra (i.e. LTSs), so the functor won't preserve the terminal object.

Comment: In a sense, this functor is the most canonical choice, as it is induced directly from the natural monad structure of $\mathcal P_f$. I'm not sure whether it is universally characterised: as you say, you can consider other functors, but they will tend to require some ad hoc choice, and therefore not be natural candidates.